# Google Maps Reverse Geocoding API returns nearest land address given a latlng in sea

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

In my project, I'm using Google Geocoding and Reverse Geocoding APIs to validate the addresses and latlngs provided by end users.

Given latlng -37.857866,144.950706, the Reverse Geocoding API (https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng=-37.857866,144.950706) returns the nearest land address.

However on Google Map web page, that latlng actually is in the sea: https://www.google.com.au/maps/search/-37.857866,144.950706

Is there anyway that I can tell Google Reverse Geocoding API to not return me the nearest land address? In real project, actually I provide the API key and specify location types, e.g. https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?key=<API_Key>&location_type=ROOFTOP&latlng=-37.857866,144.950706 and I'm just thinking if the place specified by the latlng is not a ROOFTOP address, Google should return me ZERO_RESULTS.

---

Further update: just to clarify that in my project,  customer's sites addresses are required, and some of the customers would rather provide site LatLng, therefore I need to convert the LatLng to actual address, and showing error message if a LatLng is invalid or in sea  so that customer can double check. Using the nearest land address is error-prone.

If Reverse Geocoding API is not suitable for this, then please advise the proper Google Maps API for this. Thank you.

Comment: The geocoder is for **postal addresses**.  Those are rarely at sea.

Comment: @geocodezip I think you are misunderstanding the question, clearly the questioner has had an issue where providing a latlng that has not hit an address has provided some nearby address instead. How can you avoid selection of nearest address?

Comment: @Anthropic thanks! As I said the latlng is provided by end users so could be wrong - in my example it's a place in sea.

Comment: The purpose of [reverse geocoding](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro#ReverseGeocoding) is finding the nearest street address. You cannot prevent this service from doing what it was designed for: https://google-developers.appspot.com/maps/documentation/utils/geocoder/#q%3D-37.857866%252C144.950706%26nfw%3D1

Comment: @xomena Thanks for the info and the link which visualise the API result!